# Interchange $\phi$ and $\theta$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, spherical-coordinates

Why can't $\phi$ and $\theta$ be interchanged when calculating bounds for a sphere?

The volume of the unit sphere can be calculated with the triple integral:

$$\iiint_R  \,dV\,= \frac{4}{3}\pi$$

where $R$ is bounded by:
$$0\leq r \leq 1$$
$$0\leq \phi \leq \pi$$
$$0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

But if the values of $\phi$ and $\theta$ are interchanged, the integral yields an incorrect result of 0.

I believe the same region would be covered, is my intuition wrong?

Comment: It would be nice to see what the two integrals you are comparing look like when written out, to make sure we are all talking about the same thing.

Comment: Think latitude and longitude. They have different ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume differential $dV$ has a factor of $\sin \phi$. Switching to $\sin \theta$ gives a different value.